# Using window.name as a local data cache in web browsers

Tags: jquery, json, browser, javascript

I was reading about cookies and other related client-side storage options, and read about using window.name as a data cache of sorts:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#window.name

While it certainly has things that make it less desirable - and I won't sugar coat it, it is definitely a hack in the most true sense of that word - it looks promising. I have a need to store about 10K of JSON as a client cache, right now I am sending it down with the page and when I read about this it seems like it might actually fit my needs and reduce traffic.

I am curious to see if anyone has implemented this, and what advice you could possibly give. Pitfalls? Recommendations? Differences between browsers? Some sort of usage case that would be really bad?

**Pros**

- Local storage
- Available in basically every browser that supports javascript

**Cons**

- Only supports strings
- XSS Issues
- window.name poisoning
- Information leaking to other sites

**Alternatives**

- PersistJS - http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557
- dojox.storage - http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/storage

Comment: is that 10kb of compressed JSON?

Comment: 10K uncompressed and rather verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to store local data, Flash LSO, HTML 5 Local Storage, cookies. Google gears.
Have a look at [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557), a js client library that will just do it.

This post in [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/persistjs-cross-browser-client-side-persistent-storage) elaborates a little more about it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be first implemented here: http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html.

However, if this technique takes off, I would bet money that the browsers would eventually crack down on it due to its inherit vulnerability to XSS.

A more long term solution is likely to be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_storage which grew out of the HTML 5 specification (the biggest drawback being the lack of backwards compatibility for browsers before IE 8).

Comment: Agreed, as something that isn't explicitly documented/standardised it's best not relied on... but could be a useful fallback for browsers that don't support better alternatives.