# Small through-request data storage

Tags: javascript

Is there any solutions or practices of how to organize small local data storage to keep some data between requests (no cookies or another sending data to server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**window.name** can hold several **MEGABYTES** worth of string data. It must be used carefully though.

See: [Using window.name as a local data cache in web browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035075/using-window-name-as-a-local-data-cache-in-web-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Local Storage ability is included in HTMl5. Check out this link for more information (http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html). This will not work in older browsers.